# Find the point of discontinuity of the two functions 1. $f(x)=[\sin{x}]$, [] std for greatest integer function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Find the point of discontinuity of the two functions:

1. $f(x)=\lfloor\sin{x}\rfloor$
2. $g(x)=\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}}\dfrac{(1+\sin{\frac{\pi}{x}})^n-1}{(1+\sin{\frac{\pi}{x}})^n+1}$

Both the problems are not yet solved. Please help.

Comment: Can you sketch a graph of $f(x)=\lfloor\sin(x)\rfloor$? The points of discontinuity should be obvious from the graph.

Answer (score 2):

The first one is simple once you see that $\sin(x)$ only outputs values between 1 and -1 and also repeats every 2$\pi$, so if there's a discontinuity at $x_0$, then there's also one at $x_0+2\pi$.

The second one is easier once you simplify like this: $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(1+\sin(\frac{\pi}{x}))^n+1}{(1+\sin(\frac{\pi}{x}))^n+1}-\frac{2}{(1+\sin(\frac{\pi}{x}))^n+1}$$$$ = \lim_{n\to\infty} 1-\frac{2}{(1+\sin(\frac{\pi}{x}))^n+1}$$
Now just look at $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\sin(\frac{\pi}{x}))^n$.

If $1+\sin(\frac{\pi}{x}) > 1$, then it blows up to infinty.

If $1+\sin(\frac{\pi}{x}) < 1$, then it goes to zero instead.

At last, if $1+\sin(\frac{\pi}{x}) = 1$, then it stays at 1.

Consider all three cases for $g(x)$ and look for the values when it switches from one case to another.

I hope you can take from there.

Comment: Thank you for the hints. It is clear. But how to check all cases of $g(x)$

Comment: Explain further. What do you mean by "how to check all cases"? Are you asking how to do a case distinction?

Comment: Yes. Please provide me the solution of at least one case.

Comment: Please show your workings first. Just because you have three solutions, you don't get a case distinction out of them. Same for the opposite. I don't know if I should start at the "end" or at the "beginning"